# What is the largest Stack Exchange website that got shut down?

Tags: discussion, statistics, closed-sites

[Several](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/189075/178179) [Stack](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/267415/178179) [Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214315/178179) websites got [shut down](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/367646/178179) over time. What is the largest Stack Exchange website that got shut down? I'm open to the definition of "largest", one way to define is with the number of questions the website has received.

Comment: A bit of a hack (bug?) but I think this https://area51.stackexchange.com/search?q=deleted%3a1&page=1 will give you the first 50 proposals, active and closed (adding extra search criteria beaks it). Visit each one that says: closed and look at the stats. There are only 5 pages with 50 results max so that is easy to do on your own.

Comment: Big Data would be the most satisfying answer, but I suspect it was the original Startups.

Comment: 'Big Data' ..... I see what you did there 